# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon (port 2375)

Tags: linux, docker

I have installed Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 server, using the manual on this page: https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/, so, using these steps:

```
curl -fsSL 'https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xee6d536cf7dc86e2d7d56f59a178ac6c6238f52e' | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb https://packages.docker.com/1.13/apt/repo/ \
ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs) \
main"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install docker-engine
```

I have installed it on two servers and I need them to see each other, I needed to let Docker daemon listen on port 2375 (probably doesn't matter, but using this manual: https://github.com/yeasy/cello/blob/master/docs/deployment.md)

So I created the conf file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
```

Added this to the override.conf:

```
[Service]
DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --api-cors-header='*' --default-ulimit=nofile=8192:16384 --default-ulimit=nproc=8192:16384"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
```

Then:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Tested the connection between servers like this:

```
$ docker -H 10.101.35.61:2375 version
```

The response:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1-cs4
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   e46aec0
 Built:        Mon May 22 18:46:40 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://10.101.35.61:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Tried restarting the server, same problem. Tried to run with sudo. Tried adding the user to group docker:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Didn't help. I have disabled firewall on both servers. When I check the ports open on the server with `sudo lsof -i`, I can't see anything listening to port 2375 - I am guessing Docker should be listening to it?

Comment: you need to use 'docker run' command to run the docker.  docker run -d -p 5000:5000

Comment: @Rajeshkumar, isn't 'docker run' meant for running containers? I haven't run any containers yet, I just want to make sure that docker daemon is reachable from another machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the config file in this location, create it if it does not exist:

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Put this and restart the docker service:

```
{"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]}
```

You can add more configs, documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#linux-configuration-file).

Comment: There is not daemon.json at that location (only key.json), should I create it?

Comment: Yes, it does not exist by default.

Comment: I get: the following error when trying to restart docker.service: directives are specified both as a flag and in the configurationion file: hosts: (from flag: [fd://], from file: [tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 unix:///var/run/docker.sock])

Comment: Try to remove what you did here: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf

Comment: Specially this: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS` (remove the -H fd://, you can add it to the json file if you want it)

Comment: Here in the future it's not an override--the default ExecStart line in docker-ce on Ubuntu 18.04 is `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://`. Not sure if I should both create an override to remove that argument and create a config file.